Copy a file and a folders to location based on excel list
r/excel - Copy a file and a folders to location based on excel list
I am trying to copy a list of files and folders based on the source column in a Excel to a new location.  I have an excel list of the files and folders that need to be copied  and keep partial original path (See screenshot) desire outcome.

I got this far but I keep getting an error -

Run-time error 52
Bad file name or number

here is my code:
Sub CopyFilesAndFolders()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim sourceFolder As String
    Dim destFolder As String
    Dim fileName As String
    Dim folderName As String
    Dim destinationFolder As String
    Dim sourcePath As String
    Dim destPath As String
    Dim i As Long
    

    ' Define the source folder
    sourceFolder = "C:\Users\pc50\Desktop\Source"

    ' Open the Excel file containing the list
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\pc50\Desktop\FF2.xlsx")
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1") ' Change "Sheet1" to your sheet name

    ' Loop through the rows in the Excel sheet
    For i = 2 To ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        ' Read values from Excel sheet
        fileName = ws.Cells(i, 1).Value
        folderName = ws.Cells(i, 2).Value
        destinationFolder = ws.Cells(i, 3).Value

        ' Construct source and destination paths
        sourcePath = sourceFolder &  fileName
        destPath = destinationFolder

        ' Check if destination folder exists, create if not
        Debug.Print sourcePath & vbLf & destPath
        If Dir(destPath, vbDirectory) = "" Then
            MkDir destPath
        End If

        ' Copy file to destination
        FileCopy sourcePath, destPath

    Next i

    ' Close the Excel file
    wb.Close SaveChanges:=False
End Sub


Which exact line does it fail on, and when you look at the current path variables do they look valid ?

If Dir(destPath, vbDirectory) = "" Then

And what's the value of destPath when it fails?

I do not get any value.

my structure is as follow : 3 columns (fileName, folderName, destinationFolder)

Does the row where it fails contain any values?  This is the type of question where it's difficult to help without knowing exactly what the data in columns A B and C looks like.  Here for example: sourcePath = sourceFolder & folderName & "\" & fileName - sourceFolder doesn't have an ending backslash, so that's not going to work unless folderName starts with a backslash.

I just added the excel format with data example

Before the Dir line add Debug.Print sourcePath & vbLf & destPath  Does the output look like you'd expect?

sourceFolder = "C:\Users\pc50\Desktop\Source" here you're just duplicating the path already in your data.

unfortunately ' If Dir(destPath, vbDirectory) = "" Then' is still highlighted as an issue

Right before that what does the Debug.Print produce?

nothing when debugging same line is highlighted  ' If Dir(destPath, vbDirectory) = "" Then'

Are you checking the Immediate pane in the VB editor for the output?

I see it now:  here is what I get         C:\Users\PC50\Desktop\SourceC:\Users\pc50  \Desktop\Source\Term 11-8-2013.docx
C:\Users\pc50  \Desktop\Destination\C:\Users\pc50  \Desktop\Source\

Doesn't something seem off about that?  Look at your source data and follow what your code does with it.

Changed the code. the initial error is fixed. Not I got new error: Run-time error '76: Path not found.   I changed the following :                       ' Construct source and destination paths
sourcePath = sourceFolder & "" & fileName
destPath = destinationFolder & ""

Error is now on which line?  destPath = destinationFolder & "\"  - the value on the sheet already has an ending backslash, so there's no need to add one...

the error is in this line:   FileCopy sourcePath, destPath

So - looking at the values of sourcePath and destPath, what do you see?

'sourcePath' looks correct. 'destPath' is missing the 'fileName' at the end

So you can add the filename to destPath and that should resolve it.

Not working yet. It did copy the first file as a folder instead of a document. and, the folder is empty

Don't add the filename to destPath until after you've checked if the destination folder exists...   Otherwise you will end up creating a folder with the same name as the file.

Immediate pane looks good but nothing gets created (no folder and no file).  and the error is still at this line: FileCopy sourcePath, destPath

At this point I have no idea what your current code looks like.

I just posted the whole code at the top

This should work assuming all files exist and only the last level of the destination folder path might be missing:
Sub CopyFilesAndFolders()
    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
    Dim sourceFolder As String, destFolder As String, fileName As String
    Dim i As Long

    Set wb = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\pc50\Desktop\FF2.xlsx")
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1") ' Change "Sheet1" to your sheet name

    ' Loop through the rows in the Excel sheet
    For i = 2 To ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row
        
        fileName = ws.Cells(i, 1).Value       ' Read values from Excel sheet
        sourceFolder = ws.Cells(i, 2).Value   ' folder paths are assumed to end in \
        destFolder = ws.Cells(i, 3).Value

        If Dir(destFolder, vbDirectory) = "" Then MkDir destFolder
        
        FileCopy sourceFolder & fileName, destFolder & fileName

    Next i
    
    wb.Close SaveChanges:=False ' Close the Excel file
End Sub

